# Unable to upgrade 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: 22.10

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

No valid sources.list entry found

While scanning your repository information no entry about lunar could
be found.

An upgrade might not succeed.

Do you want to continue anyway?

Comment: We have no idea how you are attempting to upgrade and whether what you attempt indeed is a valid upgrade procedure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the issue this way.

1. Open the apt directory.

   ```
   cd /etc/apt
   ```
2. Move the "sources.list" to another directory.

   ```
   sudo mv sources.list /home/User1/
   ```
3. Create a new sources.list file in `/etc/apt/` directory.

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
4. Open the Software & Updates application using the search bar or the app drawer. Change the server to the *main server* and enable the *restricted* repository.

   [image]
5. Under the *Updates* tab, select All updates or at least security updates in Subscribed to dropdown menu and click on *Close*.

   [image]
6. Click *Reload*.

   [image]

7. Update the repositories.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
8. Check for release upgrade.

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -c
   ```
9. Run the upgrade.

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```